# Insertion of query in a statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, db2

How to insert a query in an update statement?

for eg:-

```
UPDATE TABLE1 
SET 
COLUMN1 = 'select column1 as "FRUIT", column2 as "PRICE" from BASKET where column1='APPLE''
```

Comment: Do you simply want to update the price for the apple? Or do you want to also turn the apple into another fruit?

Comment: Would you like to insert the Statement itselfs in  column 1 or the value of column1?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or DB2? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Add sample table data, for both tables, both before and after update versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 
SET COLUMN1 = (SELECT column1 FROM BASKET where column1='XX' LIMIT 1),
COLUMN2 = (SELECT column2 FROM BASKET where column2='YY' LIMIT 1)
WHERE column1='APPLE'
```

Answer (score 0):

in db2 for update a table with an other table you can do this

```
  UPDATE TABLE1 t1 
  SET (t1.COLUMN1, t1.COLUMN2) = (
  select t2.COLUMN1, t1.COLUMN2 from TABLE2 t2
  where t1.key1=t2.key1
  )
  where exists 
  (
   select * from TABLE2 t2
   where t1.key1=t2.key1
  )
```